# Azure DevOps does not return LIST of service endpoints but works for SHOW of specific endpoint ID

Tags: azure-devops, command-line-interface

I have an org and a project in it for which I created a service connector of type AWS.

Long story short ->

I want to fetch in my pipeline that specific connector, delete it and create a new one.

What I was planning on doing was something like this to fetch it ->

```
env:
  AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
script: |
  az devops service-endpoint list
```

but it returns an empty array -> `[]`.

I've double checked, and yes, I have a lot of service connections created in my project settings tab, and yes, all of them (including the one I want to play with) have been enabled for all pipelines.

As a test, I've randomly tried this ->

```
env:
  AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
script: |
  az devops service-endpoint show id=uuid-of-the-service-endpoint-I-want-to-play-with
```

And guess what, it works, as it returns a JSON with the definition of the endpoint.

So, WHY oh god WHY, does the LIST *not* work but the SHOW works ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with below YAML pipeline. This is because the pipeline service account doesn't have sufficient permissions to list all the service connections in a project.

```
steps:
- checkout: none
- script: |
    az devops configure --defaults organization=$(System.CollectionUri) project="$(System.TeamProject)"
    az devops service-endpoint list
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

[image]

Please navigate to Project Settings -> Service connections -> click on More options button -> Security and grant the pipeline service account with `Administrator` role. Kindly be also advised to select the respective service account according to your job authorization scope. Then, the pipeline is able to list the expected service connections.
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!
MAY YOU LIVE A LONG AND HAPPY LIFE!

Comment: Glad to help and So will you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the default organization using `az devops configure -d organization=ORG_URL` and the default project using `az devops configure -d project=NAME_OR_ID`.

If not, you will need to include these in your `list` command as parameters:
`az devops service-endpoint list --org OrgName --project ProjectName`

---

I imagine `show` is working because you are directly referencing a service connection with an ID, so it is looking across all orgs and projects.

---

[See docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-service-endpoint-show).